# Multidimensional array/dictionary loop in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to loop through a multidimensional array/dictionary in Swift which I got from a JSON string. Originally I come from PHP so I'm probably a bit off with my approach.

My issue is that I can't seem to get into a sub-array/dict.

My code so far:

```
func getJSON(){
    let url = NSURL(string: url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as URL?)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {
            print(jsonObj!)
            let array = jsonObj!.allKeys

            for keys in array {
                print(keys)
            }

            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                //Nothing to do right now
            })
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

My JSON:

```
{
    "ArrayName1": {
        "info": "This is my first array!",
        "more": "Even more info!"
    },
    "ArrayName2": {
        "info": "This is my second array!",
        "more": "Even more info about the second array!"
    }
}
```

The function prints the key (e.g. ArrayName1) which is good, but how do I get deeper into the array? To print the "info"?

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure it's dictionary in this form [String: [String: Any]], you may want to try this.

```
if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: [String: Any]] {
    let array = jsonObj!.allKeys

     for key in array {
            print(key)
            let info = jsonObj[key]["info"] as! String
     }

}
```

Comment: I tried something similar like this but If I do it like that I cannot get all the keys for the loop unfortunately.

Because: Value of type '[String : [String : Any]]' has no member 'allKeys'.


**The dictionary is always [String : [String : Any]]**

Comment: you can still use .keys property of dictionary to get all the keys.

Comment: Thanks for sending me in the right direction! Works now :)

Answer (score 1):

- First of all don't use `NSURL` in Swift 3. There is a native struct `URL`.
- Second of all `.allowFragments` is useless as the JSON is clearly a collection type.
- Third of all don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift, use native type `Dictionary`.
- Fourth of all do the error handling at least the possible error passed by the data task.

---

All collection types are dictionaries. Use Fast Enumeration to parse keys and values. All keys and values are strings.

```
func getJSON(){
    let url = URL(string: url)!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
           print(error!)
           return
        }
        do {
           if let jsonObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:[String:String]] {               
               for (key, innerDictionary) in jsonObj {
                    print(key)
                    if let info = innerDictionary["info"] {
                        print("info", info)
                    }
               }
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   //Nothing to do right now
               }
           } else { print("The JSON object is not [String:[String:String]]") }
        } catch {
           print(error)
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Much appreciated! I guess the NSURL and NSDictionary came from some early tries with Objective-C.

Thanks again!